# Getting the distance between geographically placed objects

Tags: c#

I have an application (cad like editor) in which the user may place a lot of positional nodes (defined by their latitude and longitude).  The application needs to tell the user if these nodes are very close together - a common design error is to overlap them. What the app is doing is something rather like ReSharper or CodeRush does in the IDE - parses the project and reports problems.  A project may have several thousand of these nodes so testing for overlap becomes exponetially more time consuming as the numbers go.  At the moment I am using two for loops to get through the list.

```
for (int i = 0; i < count - 1; i++) {
     for (int j = i + 1; j < count; j++) {
         // check the distance between the i and j elements and if less than
         // a predetermined value report it
    }
}
```

I would like to get the process of identifying these into 'real time' so that the user is told at once in the event that an overlap occurs.  The looping is expensive as is the testing of the distance between nodes.  Most of the comparisons are wasted of course.

I just wonder if there is another way.  I have thought about sorting the list by lat and lon and comparing adjacent elements but I suspect that will not work nor necessarily be faster.

My other thought is to move the activity to another thread (I really have no experience of using multiple threads)  so that the values are being updated - for example storing a reference to nearby nodes in each object.  However I can imagine needing to clone the object tree for the background thread so that there is no conflict with the foreground.

Comment: I think this is a math question. Try [Math StackExchange](http://math.stackexchange.com/) and ask how to calculate the distance between two points on the surface of a sphere identified by longitude and latitude.

Comment: Distance between two points isn't the issue here, its finding all-pair distances that's causing the problem.

Comment: That's right.  My application has all the spherical geography algorithms it needs to calculate distance, bearing  etc etc.

Comment: I'd use at least some kind of spatial index to reduce the number of distances you need to calculate. A quad index grid should not be too difficult to implement and will cut down on the resources needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the user is placing these locations, the ideal solution would be to assume all previously placed points are not nearby, and with each new point or moved point, check against the rest -- this becomes a single for loop, which should be reasonable.

Another, more ideal solution however:

```
Let position of A be lat, lng.
Convert both lat and lng to a fixed-length representation
    (truncating the degree of precision to a value below which 
    you are sure they will overlap)
Let xa = lat . lng (concatenate both)
Let ya = lng . lat

Given some position B, find xb, yb.

B is 'close' to A iff | xa - xb | < delta, | ya - yb | < delta.
```

So what you can do is sort the values of xi, yi for all your input points.  When you want to check for points that are too close, you need to traverse through the list of xi's to find points that are too close together (linear time, since they will be adjacent) and then check if the same points in the list of yi's are too close.

Comment: Thanks - could you explain what you mean by concatenate?  I am sorry that I do not understand that bit - is that a dot product?

Comment: Either convert them to strings and concatenate, or left shift lat/lng by that many digits and then add the two (so you are concatenating the two binary values)

Answer (score 1):

You could look into [Tessealtion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tessellation).

Executing this on another Thread is a completely separate issue, you could do that with your nested loops as well as with a more efficient algorithm.

Comment: Running in a separate thread would let me use the nested loops.  I suppose my question there is how to do that to avoid conflict with the main thread.  Do I need to make a copy of the data to work on letting the user update the live?

Comment: @scruffy, like I said, a entirely different topic, not covered by your the question title or tags. You can do both but you probably want to share the data using `lock()`, but that changes your algo's a lot (`count` will change mid-loop).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the insights given here I think I have found a reasonable way to deal with this.

```
*First to sort all the points in latitude order.
*Then loop through the sorted list. 
*For each entry in the list compare the latitude offset (distance in meters) to the entries below it.
*If the latitude offset is less than the test distance then check the actual distance from point to point and if it is inside the test radius report the issue.
*When the latitude offset exceeds the test distance move on to the next point in the list and repeat the tests.
```

I have not written the code yet but it seems to me that if there are no overlaps then I will make a single pass.  Since overlaps are rare in practice then the total number of tests is likely to be quite small.  For 1000 points the current method makes 500,000 tests.  The new method is unlikely to make more than a few thousand.

Comment: This code did work and improved performance betwee 250 and 500 times for a list of 1000 points.